# Dieffenbachia plant leaves have drooped

Tags: houseplants, repotting

Hi I recently repotted my *Dieffenbachia* plant. I had the plant in a fast draining succulent soil but decided to switch to an indoor soil when I reported it.I also switched to a clay pot. Now the leaves had dropped, I plan to quickly repot it back in the succulent soil that's the only thing I could think of that would be causing this. Is that the right course of action?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not repot this plant again. It looks like the roots took some damage during the repotting and cannot take up water until they grow more fine roots.  These plants bud out readily from the stems.  Seeing as this one is a bit stretched out due to low light I recommend the "tough love" approach.

Get a sharp knife or plant trimmers and cut the stems at the one foot (30 cm) level.  I know you will only have a bunch of stems but it will bud out and look bushier in a month or so.

This plant will tolerate a lot more light than it has been getting so moving it closer to a window will really help.

Comment: I repotted the plant back into the succulent soil before checking your reply. However I didn't water the plant after, the soil was dripping and the plant was yellowing as if it had been overwatered. Also the pot I chose was too large for its roots. However the drooping hasn't improved. Is it too late to try the "tough love " approach that you recommend ? While it is going through this stage are you sure I should place it in more lighting? Should I continue to the leave the newly repotted soil dry while doing your approach?

Comment: It's never too late too cut a plant back, more light will make the plant bud out faster.  Seeing as the leaves are continuing to yellow and will dry and drop off you have nothing to lose!

Comment: You're right I'm going to try it now. I still haven't watered the soil when I repotted it. Is it okay to leave it unwatered?  Or should I cut the stem back and water the plant? Also do you have any advice on how to avoid this from happening in the future? I've had this plant for many years and have never experienced this before .Thank you I'm advance.

Comment: If the soil is wet do not water it. Cut it back, put it in sun and be patient, three to four weeks may pass before you see new buds.  This plant needs more light than it's been getting.